# MUI Date Calendar styling

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build calendar similar to mui  `<DateCalendar />` , i wanted to change the header 'S M T W T F S ' TO 'Sun Mon....' and also position of arrows

from:

[image]

to:

[image]

**code :**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DateCalendar } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DateCalendar";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";

export default function Calendar(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(dayjs("2022-04-17"));
  return (
    <>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <DateCalendar
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

can anyone help me to achieve this ?

Comment: Change your DateCalendar to this:  <DateCalendar
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
        dayOfWeekFormatter={(_day, weekday) => `${weekday.format("dddd")}.`}
      /> and It will show you full name.

Comment: @MaulikPatel thanks !! , do you have any idea of changing position of arrows ?

Comment: I have added solutions below. Look into it and let me know, If you've any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to achieve what you've requested. Here is the code:

CodeSandBox Link: [Full Code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/upbeat-morse-tzzspg?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00062867oziki2rt%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d000228675yc24xxd%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00032867ib3k531f%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00052867cwp6jgmi%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq4z7l9d000228675yc24xxd%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d000228675yc24xxd%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5329dx000228677mnncx4x%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A20%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A20%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FDemo.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq5329dx000228677mnncx4x%2522%257D%252C%2522clq4z7l9d00052867cwp6jgmi%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00042867l5gkzd6h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00052867cwp6jgmi%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00042867l5gkzd6h%2522%257D%252C%2522clq4z7l9d00032867ib3k531f%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00032867ib3k531f%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

**Demo.js code:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { DateCalendar } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DateCalendar";
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";
import DemoStyles from "./DemoStyles";

export default function BasicDateCalendar() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(dayjs("2022-04-17"));
  const classes = DemoStyles();

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DateCalendar
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
        dayOfWeekFormatter={(_day, weekday) => `${weekday.format("ddd")}.`}
        className={classes.muiOverrideClass}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

**DemoStyles.jsx**

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const DemoStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  muiOverrideClass: {
    "& .css-kg9q0s-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root-MuiPickersArrowSwitcher-button":
      {
        padding: "0px !important",
      },

    "& .css-cyfsxc-MuiPickersCalendarHeader-labelContainer": {
      marginLeft: "auto !important",
    },

    "& .css-nk89i7-MuiPickersCalendarHeader-root": {
      flexDirection: "row-reverse !important",
      position: "relative",
    },

    "& .css-1nkg345-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root-MuiPickersArrowSwitcher-button":
      {
        position: "absolute",
        right: "25px",
        padding: "0px",
      },
  },
}));

export default DemoStyles;
```

This way you can override the MUI classes. Please do changes according to your requirements.

Look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/upbeat-morse-tzzspg?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00062867oziki2rt%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d000228675yc24xxd%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00032867ib3k531f%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00052867cwp6jgmi%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq4z7l9d000228675yc24xxd%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d000228675yc24xxd%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5329dx000228677mnncx4x%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A20%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A20%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FDemo.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq5329dx000228677mnncx4x%2522%257D%252C%2522clq4z7l9d00052867cwp6jgmi%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00042867l5gkzd6h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00052867cwp6jgmi%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00042867l5gkzd6h%2522%257D%252C%2522clq4z7l9d00032867ib3k531f%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq4z7l9d00032867ib3k531f%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) for more info about code.